# Custom Iterators - calculating scope - batch

Tags: apex, batch, iteration

I am trying to understand the custom iterators topic [Custom Iterators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_iterable.htm)

But there is a thing which I don't get.

There is a `next()` method which divides the query size into smaller ones, am I right? In the example below there would be several batches containing 8 records.

```
global Account next(){ 
   // 8 is an arbitrary 
   // constant in this example
   // that represents the 
   // maximum size of the list.
   if(i == 8){return null;} 
   i++; 
   return accs[i-1];
}
```

How is that possible to calculate how many records I want to have in one batch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch size is specified in Database.executeBatch. Your iterator cannot choose or influence the batch size. See [my answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/98569) on how batchable uses `next` and `hasNext` from a custom iterator to determine when it is done collecting values and how those values are collected. You could, however, return a list of records:

```
global Account[] next() {
  Account[] records = new Account[8];
  return records;
}
```

However, this would act as a multiplier to your execute method:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Account[]> scope) {
```

Where Database.executeBatch would determine the multiplier. For example, if we do:

```
Database.executeBatch(new CustomIteratorBatch(), 10);
```

Given the next method from above, each call to execute would include 80 account records (10 lists of 8 records each).